# How to extract column data from list data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

How to extract the data from a list containing data.frames like the following data?

`library(tidyverse)
data <- iris %>% split(iris$Species)`

I would like to obtain the following data
`iris$Species`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `tidyverse`, you can consider `map` from the `purrr`. All of the following will work.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- iris %>% split(iris$Species)

map(data, "Species")
map(data, 5)
map(data, ~.$Species)
map(data, ~.x$Species)
map(data, `$`, "Species")
map(data, `[[`, "Species")
map(data, pluck, 'Species')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want that column in particular, just note that that data is now the `names` of the elements of `data`.

```
names(data)
#[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

If you want some other column, try

```
col <- "Sepal.Length"
lapply(data, function(x) x[[col]])
```

By the way, maybe you could name `data` something else, it already is the name of an `R` function.

**EDIT**
Sorry about the stupid mess above, much better is

```
lapply(data, '[[', col)
```